# connecting 2 layouts to activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am completely new to android, I am trying to develop a simple music player.

The app should start with a welcome screen with animation that stay till the `onCreate` function loop the device to load all the music to the playlist.

I tried to achieve this using 2 `layouts` and connected them to the `activity`, but only the second one appear, before the loop finishes nothing is shown other than a white `blank screen`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_layout);
        loading_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loading_view);
        final Animation animatable = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.welcome_screen_anim);
        loading_img.setAnimation(animatable);
        long i;
        for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++);// just a sample

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Don't use two activities, use `Fragments`read about it on google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call setContentView twice in this manner. But you can use this approach:

1. Put both layouts in the same file, inside a `<View>` tag. *Give an id to each view*
2. Make sure that both can fill entire screen
3. Change the visibility of the second one (activity_main) to GONE
4. When loaded, mark the first view (loading screen) visibility as GONE, and (activity_main) to VISIBLE

To achieve this, put the default visibilities in the XML (VISIBLE for loading screen, GONE for your content). In your activity, bind a view to an object using:

```
View loadingView = findViewById(R.id.*yourID*);
loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
View contentView = findViewById(R.id.*yourID*);
contentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Another method will be using separate activities/fragments

Comment: can u give a sample for this? I am a complete beginner and I don't know how can this be made

Comment: another question, now they both works, but the loading layout is blank, it's theme is different from the activity_main, is there a solution for this situation ?

Comment: Then you need different activities